# Arrow keys in Putty returning ^[[A ^[[D ^[[B instead of moving the cursor

Tags: python, putty, arrow-keys

Has anyone else ever had this error in PuTTy?

For example, pressing the Up Key now produces:

```
>>> ^[[A
```

Google doesn't let you search for special characters so I'm stumped at finding existing version of this problem.

---

EDIT:

So this happened after I pasted in some unicode (when, I think, the translation was already set to utf-8).

I've checked the Change Settings dialog box for different settings than my other open PuTTy windows, but the settings appear to be identical.

EDIT2:

This is fixed by restarting PuTTy, but still a nuisance.

**EDIT3:**

**How to replicate the exact same bug:**

1. Open a putty terminal to a linux PC (I'm using RedHat)
2. Open Python 2.7.*  - using the command `python2.7` (note: error does not appear in 2.6)
3. `import codecs`
4. Now use the arrow keys, and these bizarre characters appear.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15795658/564764) on a similar thread worked for me.

Answer (score 182):

In my experience that's because "bash" is not running. Simply run "/bin/bash" to enjoy colors, history and more.

Comment: Yes. from SH (shell) to BASH (born again shell). :)

Comment: There may be a reason that one needs to use a different shell, such as ksh.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/546763/157035 for instructions to set bash as your default shell.

Answer (score 11):

I've found that specifying "The Function Keys and Keypad" option to match your operating system resolves many issues.

[Putty]

Terminal -> Keyboard --> RadioButton "Linux"

(if you're using Linux) and then you can start your session

Answer (score 4):

You could try changing the 'Application Cursor Keys' mode. It's in the Terminal->Keyboard subsection of the initial configuration window (these settings may potenitally be overridden by your server).

http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.55/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#S4.4.4

Comment: as I mentioned **these settings may potentially be overridden by your server** - might anything have changed there?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think it may be an error in python or the codecs module. See my Edit 3 - does this bug happen for you too?

Comment: Nope, I did have a similar problem though. The settings in putty config fixed it for me.

Comment: Windows 10 PuTTY to locally-hosted FreeBSD VM, arrow key was on wrong line and cursor position wonky, changing this ("Initial state of cursor keys" from "normal" to "application") fixed it for me.  Thanks Paul.

Answer (score 4):

Just run the simple bash command or sudo bash in ssh. It usually works.

Answer (score 2):

Terminal >>> Local line editing >>> Force off

[See also](https://putty.org.ru/htmldoc/chapter4.html#config-localedit)

Comment: please explain your answer

Comment: Changing this option from "Force  on" to "Auto" worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For those interested in the issue, had same simptoms in a virtualenvironment, resolved the issue with

```
pip install readlines
```

See [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4289945/2927973) for details.

Comment: Interestingly, this weird problem exists ONLY for Ruby eval prompt on Redhat (RHEL). I executed the command for python 2.6.6 and followed by the error message `Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement readlines` and `No distributions at all found for readlines`.