# Python Idle - retrieving previous commands

Tags: python, python-2.7

I found Basak's helpful reply below on Stackoverflow. ([How to repeat last command in python interpreter shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289937/how-to-repeat-last-command-in-python-interpreter-shell)) Can someone please specify which button to click on AFTER selecting "history-next" and "history-previous" to change the keys in Python Idle? I didn't want to inadvertently do the wrong thing and then get stuck. Just the OK button for each button? And then type in the key I want? Thanks.

Basak:
"In IDLE, go to Options -> Configure IDLE -> Keys and there select history-next and then history-previous to change the keys.
Then click on Get New Keys for Selection and you are ready to choose whatever key combination you want."

Comment: Are you kidding? The comment says *exactly* what you should do. Read it. If you have a question about someone's comment, comment below them and @tag them.

Comment: Since I am an extreme newbie as you can see, I was not allowed to add a comment to Basak's reply due to the number of points I have. I had to write a separate question. I did not want to have to do that but was forced to. Thanks for your reply. Actually if you are brand new to a field, it is not clear what to do after clicking on History-next since the highlight changes between History-next and history-previous so was not clear at what point I was supposed to insert my custom keys. Sorry to have disturbed the community.

Comment: @angelica why don't you simply use IPython?