# How to upgrade Python version to 3.7?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu

I have python3.5 already in linux ubuntu. I have downloaded the python3.7.tar [www.python.org](http://www.python.org).

But i have no idea how to install it. How to upgrade to python 3.7? Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be posted on askubuntu.com  ?

Comment: @mahir: … possibly. Even though "Python" falls under SO's missives, the question is not *about* Python. It appears to me OP simply does not know what to do with a tar file, which falls under "general computing".

Comment: See [How do I install the latest Python 2.7.X or 3.X on Ubuntu?](//askubuntu.com/q/101591) over on *Ask Ubuntu*.

Answer (score 63):

Try this if you are on ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential libpq-dev libssl-dev openssl libffi-dev zlib1g-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3.7-dev
sudo apt-get install python3.7
```

In case you don't have the repository and so it fires a not-found package you first have to install this:

```
sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

more info here: http://devopspy.com/python/install-python-3-6-ubuntu-lts/

Comment: I don't think that'll work with 3.7 since it's not yet in the main repositories.

Comment: I tested it and it worked

Comment: I tested it and it didn't work because it lacked the PPA...

Comment: does not work on 14.04 for python3.7. there are no packages for trusty.

Comment: Tested on `Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS`. Not working. Please update answer with PPA instructions.

Comment: I just installed python 3.7 in Ubuntu 16.04 using the above instructions and using the Deadsnakes PPA . To add the PPA just execute `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa` and `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04!

Comment: Confirmed to work on Ubuntu 18.04. No additional PPA required (Jan 2019)

Comment: Confirmed to require ppa on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: why`python3-dev` and not `python3.7-dev`?

Comment: It worked for me (the last step `sudo apt-get install python3.7` did nothing as satisfied already) but just a note: you will still have to update the symbolic links manually if you want 3.7 to be the one that pops up when calling `python` or `python3`

Comment: furthermore: in case you cannot create a venv anymore and `sudo apt-get install python3-venv` fails, do `sudo apt-get install python3.7-venv` instead

Comment: some caution about making python3.7 the default, I've had some serious issues when doing this later down the road when updating other software.  I'm sure I did something wrong, but still

Comment: Add  python3.7 to update-alternatives

```sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 2```

Update python3 to point to python3.7
```sudo update-alternatives --config python3```
Enter number for python3.7

```python3 -V```

https://jcutrer.com/linux/upgrade-python37-ubuntu1810

Comment: Doesn't worksasd

Comment: How do you run it? `python --version` still gives me the old version.

Answer (score 23):

On ubuntu you can add this PPA Repository and use it to install python 3.7: 
https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/python-3.7

Or a different PPA that provides several Python versions is Deadsnakes:
https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

See also here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get (I know it says 3.6 in the url, but the deadsnakes ppa also contains 3.7 so you can use it for 3.7 just the same)

If you want "official" you'd have to install it from the sources from the site, get the code (which you already downloaded) and do this:

```
tar -xf Python-3.7.0.tar.xz
cd Python-3.7.0
./configure
make
sudo make install        <-- sudo is required.
```

This might take a while

Comment: Thanks, I have seen this answer in askubuntu. But is there an official way by Python official..?

Comment: I'd go with the PPA, but I edited my post for an official way using the code from the site.

Comment: I tried the official way, until failed in the `make install`..

Comment: I tried this but it also failed when running `make install`. I read the docs and it said that if the system already had Python preinstalled (which mine does as Python 3.6.6) you should run `make altinstall` instead. But I got the exact same error

Comment: I`m sorry, I can`t really help you with ´make install´ problems, I`d suggest using the PPA.