# Error in installing Python 3.7 - E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: python-3.7, dpkg

I was trying to install python 3.7 in my Ubuntu virtualbox using 'sudo apt-get install python3.7'.
However, I got the below output: -

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3.7 is already the newest version (3.7.4-2~16.04.york1).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython3.7 : Depends: libpython3.7-stdlib (= 3.7.4-2~16.04.york1) but 3.7.4-1+xenial2 is to be installed
 libpython3.7-dev : Depends: libpython3.7-stdlib (= 3.7.4-2~16.04.york1) but 3.7.4-1+xenial2 is to be installed
 libpython3.7-stdlib : Depends: libpython3.7-minimal (= 3.7.4-1+xenial2) but 3.7.4-2~16.04.york1 is to be installed
 python3.7 : Depends: libpython3.7-stdlib (= 3.7.4-2~16.04.york1) but 3.7.4-1+xenial2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Afterwards, I tried executing 'apt-get -f install' as recommended in the above output, but then I got the below: -

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython3.7-stdlib
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython3.7-stdlib
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 209 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,756 kB of archives.
After this operation, 66.6 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 189831 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.7-stdlib_3.7.4-2~16.04.york1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.7-stdlib:amd64 (3.7.4-2~16.04.york1) over (3.7.4-1+xenial2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.7-stdlib_3.7.4-2~16.04.york1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/__init__.py', which is also in package python3.7-distutils 3.7.4-1+xenial2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.7-stdlib_3.7.4-2~16.04.york1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**Update:**

Even though the error says that python3.7 is already there, when I execute `python`, I get the below:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Oct  8 2019, 14:14:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

And below when I run 'python3': -

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Oct  8 2019, 13:06:37) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

All I want to do is to install python 3.7.

Can anyone kindly help me with this error?

Answer (score 0):

I see following in your logs

`python3.7 is already the newest version (3.7.4-2~16.04.york1).`

It says python3.7 is already install.

can you just try 
`python` or `python3` on command line, see what it says?
if you  see something like below, it has successfully installed

```
  Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3 Oct  3 2017, 00:32:08) 
 [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on XXX
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: I updated my question with the answer to your request. Can you please look upon it?

Comment: could you try by creating virtualenv, 1) create  directory./venv  2) virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 ./venv 3)source ./venv/bin/activate  4) pip install --upgrade pip see if it works  and also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51279791/how-to-upgrade-python-version-to-3-7