# Linux Mint Update Manager doesn't work after updating Python3 through PPA

Tags: python-3.x, linux-mint

This is an issue I just solved and I share my solution here in case someone runs into a similar one.

The latest Python version available on apt is 3.5 for Linux Mint 18.3. I updated to Python3.7 via the following method (adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51279791/how-to-upgrade-python-version-to-3-7) and [this](https://mintguide.org/other/794-python-3-6-install-latest-version-into-linux-mint.html)):

Add a private repository

```
>>> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
>>> sudo apt-get update
>>> sudo apt-get install python3.7
```

Make Python3 point to Python3.7 (or whatever version you've updated to)

```
>>> sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1
>>> sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

Check the installation

```
>>> stat $(which python3)
>>> stat $(which python3.5)
```

Make pip point to the new Python version

```
>>> python3.7 -m pip install pip
```

**In case someone follows this method: a large part of Mint relies on /usr/bin/python, which points to Python2.7, so don't change where this points to to avoid breaking the system, but python3 should be safe.**

After that I noticed that mint wasn't working. When running it from the CLI, I got messages about missing packages: gi, pycurl, apturl, etc. These are not available from pip and need to be installed from apt. I tried to adapt [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057832/how-to-install-gi-for-anaconda-python3-6) by copying and renaming the relevant packages into my local /home/[me]/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages, but this is tedious.

It's not problematic in itself, as mintupdate is only a GUI for `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the files raising error messages about missing packages (mintupdate.py, checkAPT.py, etc. in /usr/lib/linuxmint/mintUpdate/), I noticed that they had were calling python3 with `#!/usr/bin/python3`, so I changed this line into `#!/usr/bin/python3.5` in each  .py file in /usr/lib/linuxmint/mintUpdate/. I tested whether updates go through, whether kernels are displayed, etc., my solution solves this issue, but obviously the safest way is to not change where python3 points to.