# Python version 3.7 is being used as the default version, even though I installed 3.8 on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have removed the path associated with python37 as well, still upon writing python on the command prompt I am given the following message.

```
C:\Users\Username>python
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: so what is your goal? what are you trying to do? I assume you want to use some specific version of python

Comment: @basilisk yes I wanna know, why is python 3.7 is still being used, and how to upgrade it to 3.8

Comment: then just write python3.8 in your terminal and not just python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upgrade Python version to 3.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51279791/how-to-upgrade-python-version-to-3-7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really don't recommend removing or adding python path or versions like what you are doing. Instead, I highly recommend using [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

In your case I think you messed up with the conda and python environment. Those are two different things and I will not recommend messing with. As you said, obviously you removed the python path and instead added the `bin/` conda path, which is wrong.

If you want to start a python project, you can just create a virtual environment with the needed python version and then that specific version will be automatically used.

Now if you want to use a specific version directly in the command prompt, then you should specify the version. For example to use python 3.8 you need to write:

```
python3.8
```

in your terminal.

Comment: I tried that as well, but was given the following error

```'python3.8' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.```

Comment: apparently you need to install python3.8 first. I don't know which OS you are using, therefore you need to search and install python3.8, then you can type python3.8 in your terminal

Comment: i have python 3.8 installed, even the IDLE version is 3.8, but when accessed with command prompt, it shows 3.7. I have windows 10

Comment: @shrekh what happen if you type py-3 or maybe py-38 or py38 in your terminal ?

Comment: ```'py-3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.```

Comment: can you try and create a virtual environment with python3.8 ? does it work or showing an error?

Comment: I opened my project in pycharm, it was using 3.8 version itself so for now I think I'll be using that only. Thanks for the help tho :)

Comment: @shrekh You need to be careful though. I think you removed the python path and instead added the conda path, which are different things.

Comment: @shrekh simply inspect if you have a conda bin path in your windows path. Remove it and add your python3 path. Don't forget to upvote the answer or close the question if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed 3.8 with the default installer, you should be able to run it with the `py` launcher. `py -0` will show you which Python versions the launcher knows about, and `py -3.8` will launch 3.8 in case it's not the default.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Anaconda 2020.07 version. It installed python 3.8.5 version. When I ran command **python --version** on CMD or Anaconda CMD, it shows 3.8.5 version. I have installed python 3.9.0 version manually and run **py --version** command, it show 3.9.0 version installed. So now you understood which command to use and when to use. Still I strongly recommend to use virtual environment for your project.

Answer (score 0):

check your path, in cmd: echo %PATH%

if you see some older version edit it inEnvironment Variables:

In the System Properties window, go to the Advanced tab.
Click on the Environment Variables... button near the bottom.