# IPython/django execute history in order

Tags: python, django

I am running django shell using IPython 5.8.0. In older versions of IPython, in order to run previous commands that had been typed, I hit the up arrow X number of times, then executed the command, then hit the down arrow and it went to the next command in order so I could quickly execute a whole series of commands in order again.

Now, when I up arrow X times and execute a command, it then jumps me back down to the end of the history list and nothing happens when I hit the down arrow.

Is there an IPython setting somewhere to change this behavior? And, if so, how do I set that?

Everything was working normally until I upgraded IPython.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4289937/7431860