# How to access command history in Python shell on Windows Terminal Bash?

Tags: python, bash, windows-terminal

I sometimes want to experiment with Python code in the Python shell. In other languages (Haskell, F#) I'm used to be able to experiment in a REPL that supports command history.

I start the Python shell from (Git) Bash running in Windows Terminal:

```
$ py
Python 3.11.0 (main, Oct 24 2022, 18:26:48) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 1+2
3
>>>
```

How do I repeat the last command, or scroll through the command history?

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4289937/126014), so I've already tried <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>, the arrow keys, and various combinations of those and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>. Nothing works. Either nothing happens, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> just prints this:

```
>>> ^N
```

The arrow keys *do* work when using the Command Prompt (`cmd`) in Windows Terminal, but *not* when using Bash.