# How come when I press the Up or Down Arrow keys in the Python interpreter I get ^[[A or ^[[B instead of history?

Tags: interpreter, python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Python shell: Arrow keys do not work on remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893053/python-shell-arrow-keys-do-not-work-on-remote-machine)

I have no idea why history won't work in the Python 2.7.2 interpreter. I get strange character groups for each of the arrow keys. This doesn't happen in Terminal. BTW I am on Ubuntu 10.04. Here is a screen shot of this hell:

[image]

**How do I get back the ability to get my command history by pressing the Up and Down Arrow keys?**

Comment: The following might be of some help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893053/python-shell-arrow-keys-do-not-work-on-remote-machine

Comment: What is the value of your `$TERM` environment variable?  How are you invoking the Python interpreter?  Are you typing `python` from a shell prompt?  If so, what terminal emulator is the shell running under?

Comment: You don't need to install any of the optional components - Python will build without them. If you need any of them, get the latest ones from your distro.

Comment: @KeithThompson I am using Gnome Terminal. Running `echo $TERM` prints out `xterm-256color`. I invoke Python interpreter by typing `python`. @VinaySajip Ok thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It looks as if you're using a build from source. It looks like you'll need to rebuild Python after installing the `libreadline-dev` or equivalent package on your distribution.

**Update:** There should be no special build steps needed, just running `make` should do. There are some messages printed at the end about optional modules which couldn't be built because of missing dependencies (in addition to `readline`, there are also `Tcl/Tk`, `zlib`, `gdbm` and `openssl` dependencies, for example).

If for some reason just running `make` doesn't work, try running `configure` again first (if `make` doesn't already run it for you).

Comment: Thanks. I just installed `libreadline-dev`. Now how should I go about rebuilding Python 2.7.2? Any specific steps I should take in the rebuilding process?

Comment: what versions of `tcl`, `tk`, and `zlib` should I install?

Comment: I recompiled Python 2.7.2 after installing `libreadline-dev` and all is in working order. Up and Down arrow keys change the command history as expected.

Comment: @vinay-sajip I am in this situation 6 years later. I have libreadline now, but am I supposed to remove the current 3.6 I have? Do I run make from the directory where the current 3.6 executable is? I'm just not sure what the right steps are. Hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: @MalikA.Rumi This is really a separate question about how to build Python from source. Consult the official documentation.