# If I rebuild Python will it break my Django installation?

Tags: python, django, build, installation, rebuild

Recently I was told I should rebuild Python 2.7.2 in order to get the Python interpreter behaving correctly as [it's been acting strange lately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495655/how-come-when-i-press-the-up-or-down-arrow-keys-in-the-python-interpreter-i-get).

If I rebuild Python will it break my Django installation and other eggs in the `site-packages` dir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django itself uses no C modules, so rebuilding Python will not affect it. Third-party apps that do have C modules may be affected though, so make sure to test them after rebuilding.

Comment: I just re compiled Python 2.7.2 and tested a Django app out and it works. I think all is well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you using Virtualenv for your work

Comment: Solid advice but not answering this specific question.

Comment: Right on I am going to start using Virtualenv as I see it is a best practice that can prevent future confusion. Thanks.