# How do you check if the PYTHONSTARTUP variable is defined?

Tags: python, variables, readline

I was looking at this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/893200/883807) and in it the author says for the original poster to check if the PYTHONSTARTUP variable is  defined. I looked around and can not find out how to check to see if it is defined.

**How do you check to see if the *PYTHONSTARTUP variable* is defined?**

Comment: Are you looking maybe for [PYTHONSTARTUP](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) environment variable?

Comment: That was clearly a typo in the cited answer.  It's now edited.

Comment: @jcollado yes I am looking for PYTHONSTARTUP

Answer (score 1):

Windows (cmd.exe):

```
echo %PYTHONSTARTUP%
```

Elsewhere (in a shell, e.g. bash):

```
echo $PYTHONSTARTUP
```

In Python:

```
import os
print(os.environ['PYTHONSTARTUP'])
```

Comment: When I do `echo $PYTHONSTARTUP` a blank line gets printed in bash. Nothing there it seems. Sorry that I posted the name as PYTHONSTART, it is indeed PYTHONSTARTUP.

Comment: So you can put `export PYTHONSTARTUP="/blah/blah.py"` in your `.bashrc` file and it should set the variable when you run bash.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's an environment variable.

```
import os

if os.getenv("PYTHONSTART"):
    do_something()
```

Comment: The name of the var is really `PYTHONSTARTUP` so when I run your code example with `PYTHONSTARTUP` and a `print 'hi'` on the next line, nothing gets printed. Perhaps PYTHONSTARTUP is missing.