# Start Python REPL and execute command

Tags: python, ubuntu

I find myself repeatedly starting a Python REPL by typing `python`, and then doing `import pandas as pd; import numpy as np`.

Is there a way to make a single command that I could run from the terminal such that a Python REPL would start in which `import pandas as pd; import numpy as np` is run automatically?

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Does this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9409833/14316282) help?

Comment: No problem good luck with your coding