# Python3.10 interpreter don't recognize my UP/DOWN/LEFT/RIGHT keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpreter

Please help me somebody.
I've installed python3.10 in Ubuntu 23.04 near python3.11.
Than I create virtualenv -p python3.10
And after that interpreter don't recognize my UP/DOWN/LEFT/RIGHT keys

```bash
➜ virtualenv -p python3.10 venv
➜ ls                                                   
./  ../  venv/
➜ source venv/bin/activate
➜ python3
Python 3.10.13 (main, Aug 28 2023, 16:45:42) [GCC 12.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^[[B^[[A^[[B^[[A^C
KeyboardInterrupt
>>>
```

But when I ran my stock python3.11 interpreter everything is OK

```bash
➜ deactivate
➜ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
➜ python3
Python 3.11.4 (main, Jun  9 2023, 07:59:55) [GCC 12.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> help()
KeyboardInterrupt
>>>
```

I've installed python3.10 from source

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.13/Python-3.10.13.tgz
sudo tar xzf Python-3.10.13.tgz
cd Python-Python-3.10.13
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall
```

May be I don't know something that I should write in some config file

- I tried to install from pyenv, but result is the same
- From [Python3.2 can not recognize UP/DOWN/LEFT/RIGHT keys in interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765441/python3-2-can-not-recognize-up-down-left-right-keys-in-interpreter) didn't helps me

```
➜ sudo apt install libreadline-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libreadline-dev is already the newest version (8.2-1.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Comment: BTW: never do sudo tar or compile code as root (and to use only for you, just compile and install on your home: it is much easier). In my opinion is not about readline, but about terminal. Install the **build** dependencies of normal python3, so you will have same support as distribution python (else you just get what building process will find).

Comment: Check out: https://devguide.python.org/getting-started/setup-building/#build-dependencies, just before mac: you will see normal dependencies for Debian/Ubuntu

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi No, I've got permission denied when compiler tries to locate to /usr/local/bin

Comment: @He3lixxx I don't know how but `pip3.10 install readline`  works. Even after I pip3.10 uninstall readline. I think it's magic

Comment: @fanishe, that's why you use `sudo make install`. You don't need or want `sudo` for any other step until the actual installation -- not for `configure`, not for `make` / the actual build, **only** for the install step. When you use `sudo` too early it puts files in your build tree that only root owns.

Comment: Anyhow, what's surprising about this? Readline is one of the most popular libraries for managing keyboard control during input, and if you don't have the headers installed **when you're compiling Python** (installing them later doesn't count!), it can't use them. `pip install readline` works later because then you're building a readline wrapper and installing it into your previously-installed Python, but you wouldn't have had to do that if you'd had readline correctly installed before the configure step.

Comment: Thanks everyone readline lib helps me. I'll write it to my knowlegde base