# How can i repeat last commands in django shell_plus

Tags: python, django, shell

I have installed django extensions and i am using shell_plus.

When i press up arrow i get weired characters like this

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Nov 23 2012, 18:02:22)
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> ^[[A^[[A^[[A
```

I am using virtual environment.

I have installed python readline both in virtualenv and my system

Comment: Really?  I press up arrow,a nd I get the las command so weird

Comment: i know but its not working on my putty terminal. i had similar problem with ipython and then i had to install python readline and that fixed problem in there. But shell plus is not working

Answer (score 0):

I think readline is not enabled in your python shell. Verify that PYTHONSTARTUP variable is defined

You can check the diagnosis here: [Seeing escape characters when pressing the arrow keys in python shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893053/python-shell-arrow-keys-do-not-work-on-remote-machine)

Comment: how can i do that in Putty. i tried this and it didn't work `export PYTHONSTARTUP=/etc/pythonstart`

Comment: Arrow works , if i use ipython from same putty and ssh on same computer but not shell_plus

Answer (score 0):

With the `shell_plus` command you need to add `--use-pythonrc` option.

Comment: I would DM this if I could. Just wanted to tell you my Son's name is Vance Gale. Pretty unique name combo :)