# No Readline Support in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, readline

I'm not getting any readline functionality in my python interactive sessions. Arrow keys just move the cursor around the screen or print `^[[A` etc. Some web searching led me to try to manually import the `readline` package, but this resulted in the following error:

> >>> import readline 
>  Traceback (most recent call last): 
>     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
>   ImportError: /opt/readline-6.3/lib/libreadline.so.6: undefined symbol: PC

I think this is a version-specific problem as this doesn't occur in the 2.6 environment that's on the machine I'm working on by default (I'm working in 2.7.10 in a virtualenv - this is the most recent python 2.7 version I can load on the machine, as far as I'm aware). It's running linux, by the way - CentOS 6.8.

It seems like [others have had this problem in some form or another](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/152) but I can't tell if their solution is out of date (do I need the readline package that has [since been deprecated](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/readline)?) and even if it wasn't I am not sure how to install the fixed version of the package (I'm not very python-savvy yet and I haven't gotten much beyond your basic `pip install` or `conda install`).

How can I resolve this error? If it's not to much to ask, a solution that wouldn't require me to switch from pip to conda would be ideal, as I'm sshing into a machine I don't have full control over and would like to do as much as possible with the tools I already have or can easily install.

Comment: is it similar to this [Seeing escape characters when pressing the arrow keys in python shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893053/seeing-escape-characters-when-pressing-the-arrow-keys-in-python-shell)

Comment: i'm guessing the environment you're sshed into doesn't support `ncurses` based on [this comment from the github link in your question](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/152#issuecomment-64094914)

Comment: @downshift I followed the top answer from the question you linked, and indeed I have no bash variable PYTHONSTARTUP (nor does /etc/pythonstart exist in either my virtual environment or out of it). Is the `ncurses` problem something that can be easily fixed?

Comment: @downshift wrt `ncurses`, it seems like perhaps the machine does have it: running ```rpm -qa | grep ncurse``` gives me ```ncurses-devel-5.7-4.20090207.el6.x86_64 
ncurses-base-5.7-4.20090207.el6.x86_64 
ncurses-libs-5.7-4.20090207.el6.x86_64
ncurses-5.7-4.20090207.el6.x86_64```

Comment: that does sound promising for `ncurses`, however seems like maybe the `readline` python package is clashing with CentOS's package `libreadline`. If you're working in a virtualenv, check if you *did* install `readline` in the virtual environment in the output of `pip list`, if so `pip uninstall` it

Comment: @downshift `readline` was installed in the virtualenv, so I uninstalled it. The problem remains, though.

Comment: i'm sorry to hear that didn't fix the problem, can you check that the CentOS platform has an updated version of its `readline` package installed as you did with `ncurses` or something like `yum list installed readline` or `yum list installed readline-devel`, see: http://centos-packages.com/6/package/readline-devel/

Comment: @downshift Doing the same as I did with `ncurse`, I get: ```rpm -qa | grep readline
readline-6.0-4.el6.x86_64
compat-readline5-5.2-17.1.el6.x86_64
readline-devel-6.0-4.el6.x86_64``` That's the most up-to-date version of `readline` and `readline-devel` according to the link you gave me, if I read it correctly.

Comment: It appears you are using a custom Python installation that links against custom libraries in /opt. You would be better served by getting Python RPM packages from IUS or SCL.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to resolve this problem (albeit in a somewhat hacky way) by configuring python to import the `gnureadline` package at startup:

1. Create a script, `pythonstartup.py`, that runs `import gnureadline`
2. Modify `~/.bashrc` to export the environment variable `PYTHONSTARTUP='pythonstartup.py'`

([Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) on `PYTHONSTARTUP`)

Putting `import gnureadline` in my `.pdbrc` file made the fix work for pdb sessions too. For some reason it still doesn't work when entering an interactive session after running script from command line with `python -i`, though.