# *** Error in `python3': free(): invalid pointer: 0xb70c3578 *** Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: python-3.x

I've install Python3.6.5 a few days ago from source code. All the things were ok, but now there's an error arises whenever I try to do something with python Command Line interpreter. That is :
When I type `python3` into my Ubuntu 14.04 's terminal, it shows,

> Python 3.6.5 (default, Jun 20 2018, 12:18:04) 
>   [GCC 4.8.4] on linux
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> >>>

And When I try to import any module, or execute any library function, It gives me:

> >>> import sys
>
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

If I try to do any thing else, it gives:

> >>> x=3
>
> *** Error in `python3': free(): invalid pointer: 0xb702c578 ***
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

Of course, `>>> x=3
*** invalid pointer: 0xb702c578 ***`
here, **0xb702c578** changes each time I enter with python3.

But When I try to compile any file written with python language(I mean **python3 file_name.py**) from terminal, it works correctly.

This question might be treated as **duplicate.** But I really didn't get anything helpful from these questions, and therefore still fetching this problem..

Comment: Any answer you get is going to boil down to "uninstall and then reinstall".  If you were following some guide or tutorial try a different one.

Comment: at least for ubuntu 14.04 you might find [ppa:deadsnakes](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) a better alternative than building from source (fd: I help maintain deadsnakes)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013060/python-3-6-1-crashed-after-i-installed-readline-module
Thak worked for me.