# Failed tests when compiling Python 3.7.4 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c, python-3.x, io, ubuntu-18.04

Since the newest python is not available from my package repository, I tried to build and install Python 3.7.4 from source. I would like to build with optimization, so I ran the following:

```
./configure --enable-optimizations
make
make test
```

`test_readline` fails with the following error message:

```
AttributeError: module 'readline' has no attribute '_READLINE_VERSION'
```

I do not know how to address this issue. Please enlighten me.

Comment: I also discovered that the interactive interpreter (after running make) causes a segfault after reading a line of input. The fault happens at myreadline.c:377. My debugger also told me that `FILE* sys_stdin` and `FILE* sys_stdout` passed into `PyOS_Readline` were optimized out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with `readline`. I resolved this issue by uninstalling `readline` and installing `gnureadline` instead, as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013060/python-3-6-1-crashed-after-i-installed-readline-module).