# readline fails in venv

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv, python-interactive

The arrow keys don't work on my server, but only when running python from the virtualenv (see example below, where I press the left and right keys).

I went over the answers in here: [Seeing escape characters when pressing the arrow keys in python shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893053/seeing-escape-characters-when-pressing-the-arrow-keys-in-python-shell): I don't have the `readline` module installed in either version of python, nor does `PYTHONSTARTUP` point to anywhere.

Any ideas?

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Oct  8 2019, 13:06:37)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
$ 
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ 
$ python
Python 3.8.2 (default, Mar  8 2020, 12:31:24)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^[[D^[[C
```

Comment: what does `import readline` reports?

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'readline'`

Comment: Are you using `python3 -m venv venv` to create the venv? Try adding the `--system-site-packages` to add symlinks to the system packages

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't fix the problem. I ran `python3.8 -mvenv --system-site-packages tempvenv && source tempvenv/bin/activate && python`, but still the arrows don't work properly

Comment: Is `readline` in the packages? When `import readline` gives `ModuleNotFoundError` it seems to be missing. Did you already try the solution of the thread you linked to just `. venv/bin/activate && python -m pip install readline`?