# Python pdb mode cannot delete

Tags: python, pdb, ipdb

```
(Pdb) n <- I got a space/tab rather than delete the "n"
(Pdb) <- What should be looks like
```

When I press a character, I cannot delete it but instead get a space/tab in pdb.

Is there any solutions towards this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you add the code producing your output? Otherwise it's really hard to guess what's the problem.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters I think what the OP is saying is that when the press backspace or arrow keys while in pdb, the output is terminal escape sequences.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893053/seeing-escape-characters-when-pressing-the-arrow-keys-in-python-shell