# Python3 input() not interactive

Tags: python-3.x

I have this test snippet

```
while True:
    input("prompt> ")
```

On Windows, when I run this script with "py", I can use the arrow keys as expected. But when I try doing this in my ubuntu command line, it will show the following output:
[image]

How do I make it such that this code snippet is interactive for any python3 installation on any OS? Why is it only working on Windows now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's about OS -
windows os is working differently from a based Linux-OS like ubuntu.
you can try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/893200/9350669

by the way, I just install python3 in my VM-ubuntu and run your script and the arrow keys work well, so you can try reinstall python or update the os. [image]

Comment: It looks like one of the links in that link has an answer.
If I import the readline module in my main python script, arrow keys work. It's a little bit wonky (Sometimes "prompt" gets replaced) but it's much better than nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
python3 -i script.py
```

Apparently this solves the problem and makes the session interactive. Lol okay.