# How can I compile a python which is usable?

Tags: python-2.7

I have compiled a python2.7.15(I have to do this because tracemalloc isn't a native pkg in python2).
But I cannot use arrow keys in the shell:

```
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> asd^[[D^[[D^[[D
```

HOW TO fix it?

Comment: (the question was a little unclear in my initial read, but okay you meant that you compiled Python from source.) There's also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893053/seeing-escape-characters-when-pressing-the-arrow-keys-in-python-shell -- different cause, same fix.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem:
`./python get-pip.py`
`./easy_install readline`