# Centos 7, Python shell witch actived virtual envirometn dont recognize backspace instead put H^

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, centos7, backspace

Im using a centos 7 server, and runing Python 3.7.9 but the problem is that when i have the python's virtual enviroment activated, open the python shell, write anything and try to delete the caracter using the backspace key on the shell apear this simbol H^, or if i use the arrows key (up,down,left,right) they put ^[[A, ^[[B, ^[[C or ^[[D isnted of show the previous line. But if i deactivate the python's virtual enviroment i can use backspace and delete the characters or use the arrow keys without any problem.

I know that those symbols are the special character asociated with the key, but i dont know what cause this behaviour i try to search on google but i cant find anything that can help me. So if anyone can help me with a post, or other wuestion in here where the problem is solved i'll be gratefull.

There ir a screenshot of the shell.
[screenshot of python shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMzE9.png)

Comment: possibly related to a lack of readline support, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893053/seeing-escape-characters-when-pressing-the-arrow-keys-in-python-shell

Comment: as an aside, always use the generic [python] tag for all python-related questions, use the version-specific tags at your discretion... note, nowadays, Python *means Python 3*

Comment: thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga this post help me to solve the error. The solutions was install gnureadline using 

`$ pip install gnureadline`