# Python3 shell prints ^H on pressing backspace key on Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x

On python3 shell launched on bash misbehaves on pressing arrows or backspace.
It prints `^H` for backspace, and I can remove these characters using `Ctrl+backspace` or `shift+backspace`.
But I don't want to do this workaround for backspace (I can do, but I can't ask all my users to follow),
So how to address this issue?.
BTW, I don't see this issue in python2 shell.
OS: 5.4.40-OpenNetworkLinux

```
python3
Python 3.8.10 (main, Jul 13 2022, 06:53:48)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.systemm^H^H^H
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893053/seeing-escape-characters-when-pressing-the-arrow-keys-in-python-shell) answer your question (ignore the ssh-specific answers)?

Comment: Tried readline with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  `stty erase ^H`. If you regret, just use `stty erase ^?`. If you don't want to do this every time, put `stty erase ^H` into .bash_profile.

Comment: Works as needed

Comment: I can add this command to `.bashrc` as well right?

Comment: Yes, by addingit to ```.bashrc```, it will be executed when bash launches.