# How can I get rid of seeing escape characters in Python3.12?

Tags: linux, shell, pip, readline, python-3.12

When I'm in Python and use the arrow keys I see the escape characters: (e.g. `^[[A^[[B^[[C^[[A^[[D`).

I want to just have the up arrow key go to last entry. So, my question is whether there's an alternative to `gnureadline` for Python 3.12.1?

I tried the following things:

- Installing gnureadline (which fixes the issue for Python 3.11), but I get `ERROR: Failed building wheel for gnureadline`.
- Installing readline (deprecated, but I thought try it out anyway), but I get `ERROR: Failed building wheel for readline`
- Installed `prompt_toolkit==3.0.43`, which didn't solve the issue. Reasoning behind it is that it seems to work in  IPython based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893053/seeing-escape-characters-when-pressing-the-arrow-keys-in-python-shell).

Running:

- Python 3.12.1
- pip3 version 23.3.2 (python3.12.1)
- Amazon Linux 2023 (aarch64)